# Fetch Requests, Core Data and Error Handling in Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift2, ios9

I'm wrapping my head around the changes to error handling in Swift 2 (was much simpler before. Thanks Apple) and in a block of code I'm using in app to load some stuff from Core Data I'm receiving a strange error.

I believe I'm doing the error handling properly, but I'm dumbfounded because in

```
if let results = fetchResults
```

I'm getting error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'fetchResults'

Am I doing something wrong with the new error handling that is causing this?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /*---------    Load Data from Core Data  ----------*/
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Peoples")
        var error : NSError?

//        let fetchResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: error) as! [Peoples]

        do {
            let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [Peoples]
        } catch var error as NSError{
            print("Fetch Failed")
        }

        if let results = fetchResults
        {
            peopleArray = results//Result

            let num = peopleArray.count
            for var i = 0; i < num; i++
            {
                strPhoneNum = peopleArray[i].valueForKey("phone") as! String
                strFullName = peopleArray[i].valueForKey("name") as! String
                phoneArray.addObject(strPhoneNum)//Add phone number in array
                nameArray.addObject(strFullName)//Add name in arrray
            }
        }
        /*---------------------------------------------------*/

        contactTable.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are visible only within the scope they are declared in, in the case of `fetchResult` the `do` block.

Put all the code to be executed if the fetch succeeds also in the `do` block and any optional binding is not needed at all because `peopleArray` is valid.

I simplified the code a bit.

```
   do {
        let peopleArray = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Peoples]

        for person in peopleArray
        {
            strPhoneNum = person.valueForKey("phone") as! String
            strFullName = person.valueForKey("name") as! String
            phoneArray.addObject(strPhoneNum)//Add phone number in array
            nameArray.addObject(strFullName)//Add name in arrray
        }
       contactTable.reloadData()

    } catch var error as NSError{
        print("Fetch Failed")
    }
```

Comment: Ah. That actually makes tons of sense. Not sure why Xcode keeps prompting me to change var error to var _ though. Seems strange, but it's working. Thank you!

Comment: That's  because the variable error is not used at all. I recommend to write `print("Fetch Failed:" \(error)")` then the warning goes away.